# VS403265: The collection's Azure DevOps Server milestone is not supported by the data migration tool: Azure DevOps Server 2020.0.1 (Dev18.M170.8)

Tags: tfs-to-tfs-migration-tool

I am working on the TFS migration to Azure DevOps service and I am using DataMigrationTool_AzureDevOps2020.0.1RTW_18.170.14715315 tool for migration on Azure DevOps 2020(18.170.30910.2) version. I have completed validate and prepare step. I am getting the below error on the Import step.

VS403265: The collection’s Azure DevOps Server milestone is not supported by the data migration tool: Azure DevOps Server 2020.0.1 (Dev18.M170.8). Please upgrade your Azure DevOps Server to one of the supported versions. The data migration guide has the latest supported versions: https://aka.ms/AzureDevOpsImport.

As per the documentation below are the latest versions
DataMigrationTool_AzureDevOps2020.0.1RTW_18.170.14715315.zip
DataMigrationTool_AzureDevOps2020.1RTW_18.181.15696196.zip
DataMigrationTool_AzureDevOps2020RTW_18.170.14735089.zip

Thanks
Sachin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This got resolved after using the Azure Dev Ops 2020.1 server and the same version migration tool.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).